Why do I get a fatal nil error when running the simulator?
I am new to app building and am following a beginner's course. They are having me do a simple exercise to replace an image element of a 'one' dice with a 'six' dice when running the simulator.
I have copied their code but when running the simulator I'm getting the errors shown in the screenshots. Could someone please assist in what I am doing wrong?
On top of this I also have created a simple line of code of 'diceImageView1.alpha = 0.5' to affect the alpha of dice 'one' without having to run the simulator, but this is also not working.error codefull code
Any help is much appreciated!
Replacing the image element when running the app.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], then read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.
